# incorrect taylor series error graph matlab

Tags: matlab

I had to write a function that gets x (vector) and number (N) and will plot the error of cos(x) minus its taylor series until N (e.g N=3 so the function is abs(cos(x)-(1-x^2/2+x^4/4)).
Here is the code:

```
function question2 (x,N)
sum=0;
s=1;
for i=0:2:N;
 sum=sum+((s*(x).^(i))/factorial(i));
 s=s*(-1);
end
y=abs(cos(x)-sum);
plot(x,y)
end
```

the graph is this one:[image: incorrect graph]

but that should be the opossite! it has to be monotical decreasing and by the end to be almost linear. Thanks

Comment: You realise that `sum` is a scalar?

Comment: sum is not a scalar if I understood correct. Here  I put x=1:3. for every x (1,2,3) I got another value for sum. Did I wrote it as a sacalar (maybe thats my mistake...)?

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I misread your code.

Comment: Are you using radians or degrees?

Comment: But assuming your code is correct, isn't this graph what you'd expect?  The error in the Taylor approximation increases as you move further away from x=0.

Comment: @theOrthanormalBeginner Yea, oops I thought it was a scalar too. You shouldn't initialize `sum` to a scalar and then overwrite it with a vector. Very strange. `sum` is also a built in function.

Comment: ok. changed name to summing but still it makes same graph...

Comment: @theOrthanormalBeginner I think the `x^4/4` should also be `x^4/24`. This is also the maclaurin series and (assuming your code is right) looks to be correct. I.e. the error is zero at `x = 0` and then grows as you move away from this point.

Comment: Jucestain, I think he saying that as he adds more points to the series, the error increases for the same value of x, not that for different values of x he gets different errors.

Comment: I meant 4!=24. my mistake. most of poeople got a graph gets down. I asked the practitioner and he said they are right...

Comment: I ran your code and it performs as expected.  For radians.  If you used degrees for x, then it won't work cause cos takes radians.  cosd takes degrees.

Comment: so the code is correct at least for radians?

Comment: @theOrthanormalBeginner Are you sure you weren't supposed to plot some error (at some set point x) with respect to N perhaps; in this case the error will decrease? The maclaurin series will approximate cos at x=0. This approximation gets worse as you go further from x=0, thus your graph makes sense...

Comment: I'll quate the question "it is known that for every x between minus infinty and infity co(x) can be developed in macloyren series in following way: [there exmaple until x^6/6!] plot the error graph when number of iterations is horizonal axis and the error is the vertical axis. e.g error for n=1 is abs(cos(x)-1)". Did I mismatched the axiss?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you expected to see the error decrease as the value of parameter N increased. However, as a number of people have pointed out, your code plots the error as a function of x. That error is expected to increase as you move farther away from the point of Taylor series expansion (in this case 0).

To go back to the first point, and show how the errors change with N, the following script calls your function for various values of N. The results, shown below, confirm that as N increases the approximation error goes down.

```
x = linspace(0, pi, 10); % x grid
% plot
figure;
question2(x, 0);  % 1 term (just the constant)
hold on;
question2(x, 2);  % 2 terms 
question2(x, 4);  % 3 terms
question2(x, 6);  % 4 terms
xlabel('x');
ylabel('Approximation error');
legend({'1 term', '2 terms', '3 terms', '4 terms'}, 'Location', 'Best');
```

[image]